# Display image PHP MYSQLI use WHERE condition

Tags: php, mysql, image, select, mysqli

I have a program that insert many records and image to a database.  I must display my records and image into the web page (forms-output.php) but only 4 records and images. If I click the link (example: link in the ref_code) and records and image must display into a new web page (forms-full-data.php) but only records and image when I click what to display. Almost all work has been completed, but when I click a field in the ref_code all records have been successfully displayed except the images. Can you help me please?

This is forms-output.php:

```php
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "profil";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo '
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-none" id="datatable-tabletools" data-swf-path="assets/vendor/jquery-datatables/extras/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf">
                                                <thead>

<tr align="center" bgcolor="#E9E9E9">
<td align="center" width="1"><b>No</td>
<td width="10%" align="center"><b>Photo</td>
<td width="100" align="center"><b>Ref Code</td>
<td width="100" align="center"><b>Name</td>
<td width="100" align="center"><b>Date</td>
</tr>
<tr>';
$no = 1; //inisialisasi untuk penomoran data
$sql= "SELECT image, name, ref_code, image, overseas, avaibility, sector, country, date, height, weight, religion, status, children, education, language, language2, experience1, experience2, experience3, experience4, experience5, other1, other2, other3, other4, other5, other6, working_experience, working_experience2, working_experience3, working_experience4, working_experience5 FROM tb_profil";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$gambar="<img src='images/" . $row["image"] . "' width='200'" . "' height='150' ></td><td align='center'>";
$data="<b>$row[name]<br><br>$row[ref_code]<br><br>$row[overseas]<br><br>$row[avaibility]<br><br>$row[sector]<br><br>$row[country]<br><br>$row[date]<br><br>$row[height]<br><br>$row[weight]<br><br>$row[religion]<br><br>$row[status]<br><br>$row[children]<br><br>$row[education]<br><br>$row[language]<br><br>$row[language2]<br><br>$row[experience1]<br><br>$row[experience2]<br><br>$row[experience3]<br><br>$row[experience4]<br><br>$row[experience5]<br><br>$row[other1]<br><br>$row[other2]<br><br>$row[other3]<br><br>$row[other4]<br><br>$row[other5]<br><br>$row[other6]<br><br>$row[working_experience]<br><br>$row[working_experience2]<br><br>$row[working_experience3]<br><br>$row[working_experience4]<br><br>$row[working_experience5]$row[image]";

echo "<tr><td align='center'>" .$no. "</td><td>$gambar<a href='forms-full-data.php?p=$data'>" . $row["ref_code"] . "</td><td  align='center'>" . $row["name"] . "</td><td  align='center'>" . $row["date"] . "</td></tr>";
 $no++;
}
     echo "</table>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

?>
```

This is forms-full-data.php:

```php
<?php
// server info
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$database_name = 'profil'; 

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database_name); 

$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tb_profil WHERE ref_code='" . $_GET['p']."'");
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
$gambar="<img src='images/" . $row["image"] . "' width='150'" . "' height='200' >";
if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
echo "<table width='100%' border='0'>
  <tr>
  <td rowspan='31' width='20'>
    <td width='180'>Full Name</td>
    <td rowspan='15' width='230'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan='31' width='200'>$_GET[p]</td>
    <td rowspan='5' width='200'>$gambar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ref Code</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Overseas Experience</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Avaiability</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sector</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Country</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Date Of Birth</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Height</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Weight</td>
    <td rowspan='17'>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Religion</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Marital Status</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Children</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Education</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Language</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>More Language</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan='5'>Experience</td>
    <td width='10'>Care For Children</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cooking</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Care For Infant</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Care For Newborn</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Care For Elderly</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan='6'>Other Information</td>
    <td>Able To Handle Pork?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Able To eat Pork?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Able to care for dog/cat?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Able to swim?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Willing to lock after elderly forbidden?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Willing to work with no off days?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Working Experience</td>
    <td rowspan='5'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>More Working Experience 2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>More Working Experience 3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>More Working Experience 4</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>More Working Experience 5</td>
  </tr>
  </table>";
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: Have you checked in database image is save properly ? means in binary

Answer (score -1):

Add `'/'`, before '`images'` catalog, while You build path.

Please read about 'SQL injection".

Please use ADODB to manage DB.